# Cannot determine why this SQL statement won't execute (Derby)

Tags: java, sql, derby

My table is set up like this and seems to get created properly. (no exceptions are thrown)

```
    String sqlString = String.format(
            "CREATE TABLE %s(%s BIGINT, 
            %s VARCHAR(%d), 
            %s VARCHAR(%d), 
            %s VARCHAR(%d), 
            %s INT, 
            %s INT, 
            %s BIGINT, 
            PRIMARY KEY (%s))",
                //
                TABLE_NAME, //
                Column.ID.name, //
                Column.MAKE.name, Column.MAKE.length, //
                Column.MODEL.name, Column.MODEL.length, //
                Column.SERIAL_NUMBER.name, Column.SERIAL_NUMBER.length, //
                Column.YEAR.name, //
                Column.MILEAGE.name, //
                Column.CUSTOMER_ID.name, //
                Column.ID.name);
```

I am trying to insert the following:

```
String sqlString = String.format(//
            "INSERT INTO %s values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", TABLE_NAME);
    boolean result = execute(sqlString, //
            motorcycle.getId(), // long
            motorcycle.getMake(), // String
            motorcycle.getModel(), // String
            motorcycle.getSerialNumber(), // String
            motorcycle.getYear(), // int
            motorcycle.getMileage(), // int
            motorcycle.getCustomerId()); //long
```

`execute(sqlString, args[])` returns `false`, but no exceptions are thrown. 
derby.log has no information about what's going wrong either.

Am I using the wrong SQL data types?

Edit:

The `execute(sqlString, args[])` method is in the Dao super-class and works fine for the other sub-classes.

The code is as follows:

```
 protected boolean execute(String preparedStatementString, Object... args) throws SQLException {
        LOG.debug(preparedStatementString);
        boolean result = false;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {
            Connection connection = Database.getConnection();
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(preparedStatementString);
            int i = 1;
            for (Object object : args) {
                statement.setObject(i, object);
                i++;
            }

            statement.executeUpdate();
            result = true;
        } finally {
            close(statement);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: So what is the exception that is thrown? What is the error message? What does your `execut()` method do?

Comment: can you give the complete string after formatting?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no exceptions are being thrown, that's the core of my problem. I edited the question to contain what execute() method does.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher the String which creates the table: `CREATE TABLE BCMC_Motorcycles(motorcycleId BIGINT, make VARCHAR(25), model VARCHAR(25), serialNumber VARCHAR(25), bikeYear INT, mileage INT, customerId BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (motorcycleId))` as for the INSERT String it looks like this `INSERT INTO BCMC_Motorcycles values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` it gets sent with the other parameters to `execute(sqlString, args)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh sorry, typo. thanks for pointing that out. **no** exceptions are thrown. (i just edited it)

Comment: you should use `executeUpdate()`  not `execute()` for a DML statement

Comment: You can replace all `set...()` methods with `setObject()` and let the driver do the type processing

Comment: @SharonBenAsher oh that's cool. It works with my other sub-class of Dao (as did the original). I did a bit of further testing and it seems that the primary keys (id) are getting inserted into the table. When I try for a specific result however I get `SQLeXCEPTION:  Invalid cursor state - no current row.`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name by executeUpdate() are you talking about naming convention, or does Derby have a method I could be using instead of this custom solution?

Comment: @AnthonyAudette: that is unrelated to Derby or naming conventions. In the JDBC API  `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` should be used to run DML statements: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()

Comment: ok, i'll look into that. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PreparedStatement javadoc for execute(String sql)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) :

> Returns:
>
> true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results

Most likely your table creation succeded, you're just getting `false` because there's no result to read.

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/) mentions in the comments, using [`PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) would be more appropriate for this kind of statement.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem but mine was that the error was that the table doesn't exist and my code was meant to create the table if it doesn't exist so after some research I found out that after the `create=true` I needed to upgrade the database i.e. `upgrade=true`.

This is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public final class DatabaseHandler {
private static DatabaseHandler handler;

private static final String DB_URL = 
"jdbc:derby:BookData;create=true;upgrade=true"; 
//connection to database
private static Connection conn = null;
//for creeat insert and oda mySql statements
private static Statement stm = null;

public DatabaseHandler() {
    createconnection();
    setupbookTable();
}



void createconnection(){
  try {

  Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
  System.out.println("Dis is a database connection error "+e);
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Dis is a database connection error "+e);
  }
 }

 void setupbookTable()
 {
  String TABLE_NAME = "BOOK";
  try {
      //use d object of connection to create a statement
      stm = conn.createStatement();
      //checks if table exist evytime d app is run
      DatabaseMetaData dmb = conn.getMetaData();
      ResultSet tables = dmb.getTables(null, null, TABLE_NAME.toUpperCase(), 
     null);
      if(tables.next())
      {
          System.out.println("Table" +TABLE_NAME+" already Exists");
      }
      else
      {
          stm.execute("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                  +" id varchar(200) primary key,\n"
                  +" title varchar(200),\n"
                  +" writer varchar(200),\n"
                  +" printer varchar(200),\n"
                  +" isAvail boolean default true"
                  + ")");
      }

  } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage() +"---Setup Database");
  }
  finally
  {  
  }
}
public ResultSet execQuery(String query)
  {
      ResultSet result;
      try {
          stm = conn.createStatement();
          result = stm.executeQuery(query);
      }catch(SQLException ex)
      {
          System.out.println("Error in Database:execQuery" +ex.getLocalizedMessage());
          return null;
      }finally
      {
      }
      return result;
  }
 public boolean execAction(String qu)
{
   try {
       stm = conn.createStatement();
       stm.execute(qu);
       return true;
   } catch (SQLException e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error occured " +e.getMessage(), 
  " Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       System.out.println("Exception at execQuery:dataHandler" 
  +e.getLocalizedMessage());
       return false;
   }
   finally
   {

   }
 }
}
```

I also created an n exec method for the Actions and Query and this is how you used it:

```
  public class FXMLbookController implements Initializable {

  private Label label;
  @FXML
  private JFXTextField title;
  @FXML
  private JFXTextField id;
  @FXML
  private JFXTextField writer;
  @FXML
  private JFXTextField printer;
  @FXML
   private JFXButton save;
  @FXML
  private JFXButton cancel;
  DatabaseHandler database;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
     database = new DatabaseHandler();
}    

@FXML
private void addBook(ActionEvent event) {
    String bookId = id.getText();
    String bookTitle = title.getText();
    String bookPublisher = printer.getText();
    String bookAuthor = writer.getText();
    if(bookId.isEmpty() || bookTitle.isEmpty() || bookPublisher.isEmpty() || 
    bookAuthor.isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No field must be left empty", 
  "Error Occured", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
     }
    else
    {
        /*+" id varchar(200) primary key,\n"
                  +" title varchar(200),\n"
                  +" writer varchar(200),\n"
                  +" printer varchar(200),\n"
                  +" intcode varchar(100),\n"
                  +" isAvail boolean default true"*/
        String quIn = "INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES("+
                "'" + bookId+"'," +
                "'" + bookTitle+"',"+
                "'" +bookAuthor+ "',"+
                "'" + bookPublisher+"',"+
                "'" +"true"+"'"+
                ")";
        System.err.println(quIn);
        if(database.execAction(quIn))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success", "Success", 
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: ", " Not inserted", 
  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        };
    }
}

@FXML
private void cancel(ActionEvent event) {
}

}
```